# How to extract chunker in results?

Tags: nltk

I was trying to extract the verbs and nouns (in their stemmed forms) of each sentence in a text file contains 1000 questions. And I want to compute the overall frequency (# of occurrences / # of questions) of the verbs and nouns across all the questions. Find all frequent verbs and nouns so that their overall frequency are greater than a threshold (for example, 0.2, making it a parameter)

So the output would be 
Q1: frequent verb1, frequency1; frequent verb2, frequency2; ...; frequent noun1, frequency 1,....

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize, RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

with open('test.txt', encoding='utf8',) as Test_file:
     text = Test_file.read()


def stop_words(a):
     stop_words= set(stopwords.words('english'))
     important_words = []
     for w in a:
         if w.lower() not in stop_words:
             important_words.append(w.lower())
     return important_words

def take_words(a):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(a) 
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
    sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in sentences]
    return sentences


def stem_words(a):
    words_stem= []
    PS = PorterStemmer()
    for r in a:
        words_stem.append(PS.stem(r).lower())
    return words_stem


def chunking(a):
    Grammar = r"""
    NN:       {<NN.*>+}
    VB:       {<VB.*>+}          
    """
    ChunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(Grammar)
    for w in a:
        Chunkit = ChunkParser.parse(w)
```

And Now I don't know how to go next step? Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with chunking. All you want seems to be counting (stemmed) tokens, with separate counts for verbs and nouns. So you need POS tagging and stemming, but no chunking at all...

Comment: Indeed, there's no reason to build a chunker here. You basically use it to check if a token is a noun or a verb. Just POS-tag your sentences and then do: if tag.startswith('NN'): [code for noun] ... elif tag.startswith(VB'): [code for verb] ...

Comment: Thank you guys. I tried the POS method and it is useful. But the accuracy is not good enough. Do you know any method to improve its accuracy?